# Express session cookie is not set because of proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, proxy

I'm trying to use express session but my host has a proxy that serves as anti-ddos, the problem is that it changes the ip, so the client does not see the real ip of my server, I tried everything on all forums, impossible to find someone who has the same problem as me, I send you my current code.

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config({path:"./.env"});
const express = require('express');
const SocketIo = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

const loadMidelwares = require('./loaders/loadMidelwares.js');
const loadRoutes = require('./loaders/loadRoutes.js');
(async () => {
    const corsOpt = await loadMidelwares(app);
    // load routes ...
})();


const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

my midelwares :

```
const corsOpt = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: "*", //`http://103.252.88.145:${process.env.PORT}`, // i allready test the ip and nothing change.
    methods: ["POST", "PUT", "GET", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"],
};

    app.set('views', './web');
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.set('trust proxy', (ip) => {
        const allowed = ["127.0.0.1", "103.252.88.145"];
        return allowed.includes(ip);
    });
    app.set("config", require('../config.js'));
    app.use(
        bodyParser.json(),
        bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }),
        cookieParser(),
        expressSession({
            name: "session",
            secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: true,
            cookie: {
                maxAge: 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 3 jours
            },
            store: new MySQLStore({
                host: process.env.DBhost,
                port: process.env.DBport,
                user: process.env.DBuser,
                password: process.env.DBpassword,
                database: process.env.DBdatabase
            }),
        }),
        cors(corsOpt)
    );

    (async () => {
        const db = await loadDb();
        app.set('db', db);
        db.query(`DELETE FROM sessions`);
    })();
```

Thanks!